# Efficient algorithm for determining whether value of convex optimization program is below some value?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Let $X$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, let $c \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

I want to know whether

$$
\min_{x \in X} x^\top c < 0.
$$

Obviously, I can (efficiently, with standard software) evaluate the program, then compare its value to zero, but it's easy to see how this is wasteful.

My question is: is there a standard algorithm that works with the composed problem directly and is much more efficient as a result (A naïve method would be to just check each iteration of some sort of interior point method then terminate if it goes below zero -- is there something better)?

Comment: Is $x' := x^T$?

Comment: Does your convex set has analytical form? say, $f(x)\leq 0$ where $f(x)$ is a convex function. If so, your problem can be solved analytically by standard convex analysis theory. If it is not the case, you have to specify what information we have, say, we could know that whether a point lies in $X$ and get its normal cone and tangent cone.

Comment: Just remove the linear function from the objective and turn it into an inequality constraint. Then solve the feasibility problem. Strict inequality would be better.

Comment: @foxell: I do not think that I can write down such an $f$. But if I could, what do you have in mind with 'standard convex analysis theory'? How do I tell if $x \in X$? For the proximate problem, it is because the problem is actually $min_{y \in Y} f(y)^\top c$ where $Y$ is a simple set (a box, say), and $f$ is a well behaved function.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Yes, I understand your suggestion and it seems like a good one. If you can jot it down as a solution that shows how feasibility problems can be posed as a standard optimisation problem (as far as I can tell, primitives which solve the feasibility of are not present in all convex optimization software?) and give some heuristic reasoning about why this reduction should be faster than the simple formulation I would gladly accept it.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: I understand. Thank you for your suggestion, I still haven't totally figured out the best way to go about it, but your insight is helpful. For what it's worth at least one (not-open-source) optimisation software offers what I am asking about as a built-in primitive: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/bestbdstop.html#parameter:BestBdStop.

Comment: @foxell: Thanks for your solution. Your assertion of equivalence is not clear to me. To take a simple, heuristic example of my confusion: how does your proposed method avoid the case where it can immediately move to a value < 0 versus moving to another value > 0 but which seems very likely to lead to a value $\ll$ 0 the iteration after that?

Comment: How to describe the convex set $X$, by a set of inequalities, or by oracle (black box)?

Comment: @RiverLi see my answer to 'foxell' above. But do you have a solution in the simpler case of $X = \{x: Ax \le b\}$?

Comment: @user39430  For this case, you may use the Affine-Scaling Algorithm. See wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karmarkar%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is equivalent to solve:
$$ \min \delta_X(x)+c^Tx$$
and determine whether the minimal value is less than 0. If the projection onto set $X$ is easy to solve, the standard method is Douglas-Rachford splitting. Specifically, its iterations are given as:
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
y_{k+1} & =x_{k+1}-\gamma c \\
z_{k+1} & =\text{proj}_{X}(2y_{k+1}-x_{k+1}) \\
x_{k+1}&=x_k+y_{k+1}-z_{k+1}
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
where $\gamma>0$ is a parameter. It is proved that $y_k,z_k$ will converge to the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the dimension of your problem is not too large I suggest using a primal-dual interior point method (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior-point_method) - once the value at the primal variables goes below 0 or the value at dual variables goes above 0 you can stop.